# Getting problem with NSUndoManager undo and redo actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsundomanager

I am using `NSUndoManager` for undo and redo options. I drag a view from one place to another. Dragging done multiple times. Now if do undo its working fine. It moves to the first place. But if I do redo the last action is missing. I used a pan gesture for dragging. At starting of dragging I saved the previous location in undo manager. **The problem is the last action is not saved in undo manager.** If I do redo the first action is the current action of view. So the view is not moving, because the first action is already saved undo manager. How to handle these kinds of scenarios.

This code is a call to do an undo manager.

```c
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
     CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

     if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        [self subviewMoved:recognizer.view center:recognizer.view.center];
     }

    UIView *subView = recognizer.view;
    subView.center = CGPointMake(subView.center.x + translation.x, 
    subView.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];

}
```

This is undo Method.

```
-(void)subviewMoved:(UIView*)view center:(CGPoint)origin{
      view.center = origin;
      [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]subviewMoved:view center:origin];
}
```